# Operator to test for falsy values with zero treated as truthy

Tags: javascript, zero, falsy

Is there a minimalistic syntax to do the same as `x === 0 ? true : !!x`.
The goal of this expression is to avoid the exclusion of zero as falsy and yet make sure other falsy values do are converted to `false`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Comment: How is `??` going to help?

Comment: Is it only zero you want to exclude? Not `NaN` or  `""`?

Comment: @JayCodist: yes, just zero.
@Teemu: I fail to see how `??` helps

Comment: You want to allow *any truthy value* and `0`? Including objects, arrays, strings etc?

Comment: What is wrong with your existing code?

Comment: @deceze: I want to test a condition where `null` and `undefined` should return a falsy but a zero-value should pass.

Comment: @SalmanA: In short I am correcting a bug, the current code is working I just was curious if it could be made shorter or more efficient since it seemed like the type of expression that could be managed by some peculiar operator.

Comment: So, would `typeof x === 'number'` be an option, or is that too restrictive…?

Comment: @deceze: this could actually make for a smart refactoring, it does answer the specs and is clean enough !

Comment: Ternary operators are already designed to be excessively succinct as to be practically unreadable... you want something *even shorter*?

Comment: @TylerH: that a good point, I'll leave it at the current "shortiness", should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you want to allow *any number*?

```
typeof x === 'number'
```

Comment: He might want to treat NaN as falsy as well which needs an extra `&&`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68981254/operator-to-account-for-zero-but-not-undefined-null/68981425?noredirect=1#comment121915138_68981254…

Comment: FWIW, this solution is technically one character longer than OP's current solution.

Comment: This doesn't really do it. The OP wants to test for boolean, with all numbers considered truthy. And this will evaluate to false, if x is a truthy value in another type

Answer (score 2):

The most minimalist syntax I can think of is

```js
x === 0 || Boolean(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that there's a better solution than what you've got. You could also use `!!x || x === 0` though

Comment: That would not always return a boolean

Comment: That is true, yeah. I'll amend my answer but there is already a better answer above.